# How to divide by decimal quickly?

Tags: divisibility

My friend asked me to help solve a problem in which she cannot use a calculator.

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
32.45 \enclose{longdiv}{253.11} \\[-3pt]
\end{array}
$$

What is the best method to approach this in an exam situation - i.e. relatively quickly?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just focus on finding 
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
3245 \enclose{longdiv}{25311},\\
\end{array}
$$ since $\frac{253.11}{32.45} =\frac{25311}{3245}$. By the way, is the exam multiple choice? And what type of answer does it want (decimal form, or remainder?)?

Comment: That is true. No, it is not multiple choice. With the answer in decimal form.

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://mathlearners.com/vedic-mathematics/division-in-vedic-mathematics/

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to display a long division using MathJax

Answer (score 2):

May be
$$32.45=\frac{3245}{100}=\frac{5 \times 11 \times 59}{100}$$
$$253.11=\frac{25311}{100}=\frac{3 \times 11 \times 13 \times 59}{100}$$ could help to get
$$\frac{32.45}{253.11}=\frac 5{39}$$
$$\frac{253.11}{32.45}=\frac {39}5=\frac {78}{10}=7.8$$

Comment: It was quite a good idea to factorise the numbers.

Comment: @Henrik. I suppose that this was the goal of the problem. Dividing by $5$ or by $11$ is simple mentally; by $13$, they used to teach it at my time (looooong time ago !).

Comment: That's great but how do you get to the factorisation? What is the thought process behind - if I can ask that? Do you just start with 5 or 10 usually? I can see as soon as you start doing that - it simplifies quickly.

Comment: @alicook. Multiple both numbers by $100$ to kake them whole numbers; this does not change the ratio. Now, have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule and use mental calculation.